# ASP Core migration 1.1 to 2.0 : Controller/Views scaffolding multiple exceptions

Tags: scaffolding, asp.net-core-2.0

I migrate my asp core 1.1 project to 2.0 with success, I can build, and launch debug with no problem.

But when using the scaffolding to generates Controllers and Views (VS Community 2017)
**Add > Add Scaffolded item > MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework**

I've got several exceptions when launching the process on any POCO, as example I picked the first thrown exception 
**=> I changed the default templates to match my pattern (ie DI of generic Service Layer within each controller**) and on the project before migration (on asp core 1.1) **everything worked fine.**

```
There was an error running the template C:\Users\Nicolas\Documents\Visual Studio 
2017\Projects\WebPortal\WebPortal\Templates\ControllerGenerator\MvcControllerWithContext.cshtml: Template Processing 
Failed:Template(45,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a using 
directive or an assembly reference?) Template(65,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Dictionary<,>' could 
not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Template(118,28): error CS0246: The type or
 namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0() at 
Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args) at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args) at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
```

And the concerned lines of my Controller template sued for the scaffold:

```
var modelProperties = new List(); (line 45)
var relatedProperties = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>(); (line 65)
var dependencies = new List(); (line 118)
```

Obviously I import the corresponding namespace for List and Dictionary.
If I remove these lines I've got other exceptions which were not thrown when the project was on .net core 1.1 version.

Here is the .csproj for 2.0 project (scaffolding fails)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssetTargetFallback>$(AssetTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</AssetTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-WebPortal-ed2c59f1-3859-46e1-af11-xxxxx</UserSecretsId>
    <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And the .csproj for 1.1 project (scaffolding works with same template)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-WebPortal-ed2c59f1-3859-46e1-af11-xxxxx</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Anyone could help on that point ? I can supply the templates off course.
Regards

Comment: I precise that I also tried with CLI commands, even to force the sdk used but with same result : `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator --project C:\Users\Nicolas\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WebPortal\webportal\WebPortal\WebPortal.csproj --no-build controller --force --controllerName FeaturesController --model WebPortal.Models.SymoModels.Feature --dataContext WebPortal.Data.ApplicationDbContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --noViews --dispatcher-version 1.0.0-rtm-10308`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make my template works on .net core 2.0, I checked the differences between my templates and the templates from the repo [Templates Github repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/tree/dev/src/VS.Web.CG.Mvc/Templates), and here are the mandatory modifications :

**Templates\ControllerGenerator\MvcControllerWithContext.cshtml**

Add :

```
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Linq;
```

in addition of :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

So the 'header' looks like :

```
@inherits Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating.RazorTemplateBase
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

**Templates\ViewGenerator\List.cshtml**

Add :

```
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Linq;
```

so the 'header' looks like :

```
@inherits Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating.RazorTemplateBase
@using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore
@using System.Collections.Generic
@using System.Linq
@@model @getenumerabletypeexpression(Model.ViewDataTypeName)
```

Then make the following replacement :

```
IEnumerable<PropertyMetadata> properties = Model.ModelMetadata.Properties;
```

replaced by

```
var properties = Model.ModelMetadata.Properties;
```

I didn't have to change anything else to my other view templates, and I don't use other controller templates